# How to remove a folder with «everyone deny delete»?

Tags: acl

I choose to sync my documents with iCloud in OS X. Because it created unattended and unepected changes, I preferred not to sync with iCloud.  A remnant folder was left at the first level of MyUser and I am not able to delete it.

I tried a shell command that was suggested in the Apple forum and got this message:

```
cd /Users/Nous/Bureau \:\ iMacIntel 

Nous@iMacIntel Bureau : iMacIntel % /bin/ls -dleO@ .

drwx------@ 33 Nous  staff  sunlnk 1056 19 jul 14:56 .

    com.apple.macl   288 

 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

The folder seems to be owned by a group being denied to delete it.

I have tried:  `sudo chmod -a "everyone deny delete` ...  and it does not work.

Anybody has a clue to my problem ?  I am not a coding pro at all.

Comment: There may be group ownership, but it has no rights. The *nix way of doing this would be to `chmod -R 777 .`, then nuke it away. I assume this would be allowed on a Mac. If that does not work, then post what you put in and the error message. Telling us `and it does not work` is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion how to nuke the folder.  Is that a recommendation shared by the many ?  I am not used with these nuclear stuff and would not like to create more problems.

Comment: Hello Bib ... Sorry for the delay.  Was busy killing other bears.  Can you precise the exact command you suggest considering the folder I described above.  The problematic folder is: «Bureau / iMacIntel» without «».

Comment: Like I said, I am not used to Terminal.  I did tried my understanding of your suggestion: «chmod -R 777 /Users/Nous/Bureau \:\ iMacIntel»  and got this long reply:

Comment: ... that you can read here: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1y7f99nf1rnsu4g/Terminal%20reply%20to%20chmod%20command.pdf?dl=0

Comment: ➜  ~  chmod -a "group:everyone allow delete"  Pictures
chmod: No ACL present 'Pictures'
➜  ~  chmod -R 777 Pictures
➜  ~  rm -R Pictures
rm: Pictures: Operation not permitted
 ➜  ~  sudo rm -R Pictures
rm: Pictures: Operation not permitted --- Any ideas?

Comment: Anybody have a clue about the above problem ?  I would gladly accept your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can wipe the file's access control list with

```
chmod -N <file>
```

If you want, or just remove that specific access control entry with

```
chmod -a# 0 <file>
```

Comment: Hello Benjamin ... I appreciate your help and comments.  

That folder was created by the OS when I first wanted to sync the Documents folder Apple offered and, soon after, decided not to do so realizing that there was more than I understood about this process.            Would such command possibly affect my data structure or reliability in any way?

Comment: Without offensing you, I would like to know if you have full experience about these commands ?

Comment: The question was how to remove the resource and I answered how to do this. Whether you SHOULD do this - the decision is up to you.